# Python while loop driving me nuts! PLEASE

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This script is supposed to continuously read  different rfid tags once, print out the tag number and send it to the remote xbee. However, it keeps reading tags in a continuous loop. I want it to read a tag once display the result and send it to the remote xbee, then wait for a different tag and repeat the process.

```
def main():
    ann = as3992_api.AntennaDevice()

    print "Firmware info: %s\nHardware info: %s" % ann.get_system_info()
    print "Activating antenna"
    ann.set_antenna_state(True)
    print " Reading Tags:"
    while True:
        try:
            for epc, rssi in ann.iter_epc_rssi():
                #time.sleep(1)
                print "---------------------------------------"
                print "Scanning Tag..."
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Tag code epc:" +epc.encode("HEX"),rssi
                #send tag info to remote xbee
                xbee.tx_long_addr(frame='0x1', dest_addr=XBEE1_ADDR_LONG, data=epc.encode("HEX"))
                print "---------------------------------------"
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Sending tag information to XBee 1 ..."


        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ann.set_antenna_state(False)
            break





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So...do you ever invoke `CTRL + C`?

Comment: theres nothing in here that checks for a different tag

Comment: The line : # for epc, rssi in ann.iter_epc_rssi():  is the line that  reads new tagss. It work but i want it to read a tag once and send information.

Comment: It reads tags, Hence the line for epc, rssi in ann.iter_epc_rssi():.

Comment: How do i tell python to excute a function/command once in a while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    ann = as3992_api.AntennaDevice()

    print "Firmware info: %s\nHardware info: %s" % ann.get_system_info()
    print "Activating antenna"
    ann.set_antenna_state(True)
    print " Reading Tags:"
    ok=[]
    while True:
        try:
            for epc, rssi in ann.iter_epc_rssi():
                if epc+rssi not in ok:
                    #time.sleep(1)
                    print "---------------------------------------"
                    print "Scanning Tag..."
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print "Tag code epc:" +epc.encode("HEX"),rssi
                    #send tag info to remote xbee

                    xbee.tx_long_addr(frame='0x1', dest_addr=XBEE1_ADDR_LONG, data=epc.encode("HEX"))
                    print "---------------------------------------"
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print "Sending tag information to XBee 1 ..."
                    ok.append( epc+rssi )
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ann.set_antenna_state(False)
            break
```

Comment: basd, You got it right, you just saved me woaw, Certified Python Guru!!!! However, it gives me some error about epc+rsssi . str and tuple error. if i omit the rssi, it works fine... Thanks once again!